# ASP.NET - Fill/update row in gridview when a textbox loses focus

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, textbox

I have the following gridview that is inside an updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" Text="Novo Artigo" />
        <asp:GridView ID="Dados" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Grid">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Artigo">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Artigo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="Artigo"
                        PopupControlID="PanelArtigos"
                        >
                        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Descrição">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Descricao" runat="server" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IVA">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="IVA" runat="server" Width="40px" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pr. Unit.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="PU" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="% Desc.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Desconto" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UN">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="UN" runat="server" Width="50px" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quant.">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Quantidade" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Liquido">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TotalLiquido" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="RemoveArtigo" runat="server" OnClick="RemoveArtigo_Click">Remover
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle Font-Size="Small" />
            <RowStyle Font-Size="Small" CssClass="grid" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

As you can see, i have some textbox's.

When i change a value in a textbox, for example, the Desconto value, and leave that textbox, i want that the row where i am to be updated, using the new value present in the textbox. It's like a TextChanged or onBlur, but inside the update panel it's not working.

what is the best way to do it?

I am using VB.NET.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

When adding the OnTextChanged="Desconto_TextChanged" i receive this compilation error:

> Compilation Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the compilation
>   of a resource required to service this
>   request. Please review the following
>   specific error details and modify your
>   source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: BC30456:
>   'Desconto_TextChanged' is not a member
>   of 'ASP.index_aspx'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 204:
>    Line 205:
>    Line 206:
>    Line 207:
>    Line 208:
>
> Source File:
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Facturas\Facturas\index.aspx
>   Line: 206

Comment: I modified the Event Handler in the code behind of textbox to protected instead private, and now it's working like a charm.
I can accept both answers as the solution, because they helped me to solve part of the problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBox` controls will not initiate a postback by default. you can set `AutoPostBack` to `true` for each textbox control.

Comment: But which event can i use to ensure that the row is updated when the AutoPostBack is done?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the event you need is `TextChanged`. Like lincolnk said, you need `AutoPostBack` set to `True` for the textbox to fire the postback. Then, inside the event handler, call `Dados.DataBind()` to reload the GridView's data.

Comment: When i create the TextChanged event in the Desconto button and try to compile, i receive this error:

Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'Desconto_TextChanged' is not a member of 'ASP.index_aspx'.

Is it because of the gridview is inside an update panel? Cannot find it that way?

Comment: It should still be visible inside the update panel. How are you creating the TextChanged event? It sounds like the event handler is not being set properly.